# async/await actions in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, async-await, vuex

I am wondering how to use async/await actions in Vuex. The [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) provide this syntax as an example:

```es6
actions: {
  async actionA ({ commit }) {
    commit('gotData', await getData())
  },
  async actionB ({ dispatch, commit }) {
    await dispatch('actionA') // wait for `actionA` to finish
    commit('gotOtherData', await getOtherData())
  }
}
```

Following this example, I have:

```es6
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        // other state vars here
        resource: null
    },
    mutations: {
        // saveValues
        setResource(state, payload) {
            state.resource = payload;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async getResource({ commit, dispatch }) {
            var resource
            console.log('resource1: ' + resource)
            Vue.http.get('https://mysite/api/getResource')
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log('get resource')
                    var data = response.body;
                    resource = data.access_resource;
                    console.log('resource2: '+ resource)
                    commit('setResource', resource);
                    var foo = store.getters.resource;
                    console.log('resource3: ' + foo);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
        async getSomeApi({ commit, dispatch }) {
            console.log('getting api');
            await dispatch('getResource');
            var resource = store.getters.resource;
            console.log('resource4: ' + resource);
            Vue.http.get('https://somesite/api/someapi?resource=' + resource)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("got something from somesite")
                    var data = response.body;
                    // do something with data -> payload
                    dispatch('saveValues', payload);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    },
    getters: {
        resource(state) {
            return state.resource;
        }
    }
});
```

However, even following the syntax example found in the docs, when I run this code, the async/await seem to be completely ignored. When I look at the logs, I see, in the following order:

- `getting api`
- `resource1: undefined`
- `resource4: null`
- `get resource`
- `resource2: <expected-value>`
- `resource3: <expected-value>`

I expect the console.log statements to print out in numerical order. I would appreciate if someone could clarify what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're not `await`ing the `Vue.http.get()` promise in the `getResource()` method, so `await dispatch('getResource')` will resolve before the HTTP request has resolved.

Trimmed down:

```es6
async getResource() {
    let response

    try {
        response = await Vue.http.get('https://mysite/api/getResource')
    } catch (ex) {
        // Handle error
        return
    }

    // Handle success
    const data = response.body
}
```

Comment: from your answer "await dispatch('getResource') will resolve before the HTTP request has resolved." does it mean that async process will be finish sooner than sync process?

Comment: @KickButtowski I think he mean "getResource" will finish executing before "Vue.http.get" since "getResource" does not wait for "Vue.http.get" to finish.